# How to execute single input validation by @FacesValidator using ajax event and render message?

Tags: ajax, jsf

usage:JSF 2.3.2 Mojarra

while adding ajax to my jsf i met such a case:

cannnot refresh: **h:message id="phoneNumber-msg"** during fulfill the form

```
<h:messages id="validation-messages" styleClass="validation-messages"/>
<h:form>
    <h:outputLabel for="phoneNumber">Phone number</h:outputLabel>
    <h:inputText id="phoneNumber" value="#{bean.phoneNumber}">
        <f:validator validatorId="validators.PhoneNumber"/>
        <f:ajax event="blur" execute="@this" render="phoneNumber-msg"/>
    </h:inputText>
    <h:message id="phoneNumber-msg" for="phoneNumber"/>
    [...]
    <h:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{userDetails.submit}"/>
</h:form>
```

and **validators.PhoneNumber** is a @FacesValidator:

```
@FacesValidator("validators.PhoneNumber")
public class PhoneNumberValidator implements javax.faces.validator.Validator {
    @Override
    public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) throws ValidatorException { ... }
}
```

ADDITIONALLY

The validation work properly(message from *validators.PhoneNumber* occured in both: *id="validation-messages"* and *id="phoneNumber-msg"*) when refreshed by the "Submit" button that ends the form:

```
   <h:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{userDetails.submit}"/>
</h:form>
```

If you think about different validation way -> at EmailAddress input I used my own class anotation (*EmailAddressValidator implements ConstraintValidator*) which validates by @ValidEmailAddress on the bean used in the form - it renders the email validation message properly, but here I would like to validate PhoneNumber in a different way.

---

### Is it possible to render *id="phoneNumber-msg"* (that means proceeding *validators.PhoneNumber* during fulfill the form?

Comment: Please improve your title, it is (almost) a summary of tags, see [ask], and provide JSF version and implementation like requested in https://www.stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info. And did you try without a custom jsf tag? (to make a [mcve]?)

Comment: Custom tag does not make a difference here. With or without results are the same.

Comment: So remove that from your question. Make it an [mcve]. Always, always, always try to reduce the code as much as possible when debugging.

Comment: Is there an error logged for `cannnot refresh: h:message id="phoneNumber-msg"` in javascript console or server console / log files? If so, please also add the stack trace if present.

Comment: No, there is no error logged in javascript console nor server console. Moreover there is no data sent in browser inspector (at tab Network) when i change input value in `<h:inputText id="phoneNumber...>`. It seems like an existance of `<f:validator validatorId="validators....>` affects to `<f:ajax event="blur" execute="@this"...>` so execute cannot be invoked. Curious.